# How to build F# projects with Azure Devops Pipelines? I get error 'The target "Build" does not exist in the project'

Tags: f#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm tinkering with AzureDevops for the first time, to set up some CI tasks.

I have a public repository (opensource) with a solution (.sln) that has 3 F# projects. The solution builds fine in Windows/Mac/Linux.

However, if I try to set up a build pipeline with Azure Devops Pipelines, I get the error:

> src\GWallet.Backend\GWallet.Backend.fsproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The
>   target "Build" does not exist in the project.

[Logs here.](https://dev.azure.com/diginex/geewallet/_build/results?buildId=2&view=logs)

My suspicion is that the build agent that is assigned to execute this doesn't have the F# tooling installed. Because I guess that the target "Build" is defined in the well-known `Microsoft.FSharp.Targets` file.

How to configure the Windows(VS2017) build agent to install the F# tooling so that this file is discoverable?

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent? private agent?

Comment: the default VS2017 agent, which I guess is not private?

Comment: yeah confirmed, quoting: `Pool: Hosted VS2017; Agent: Hosted Agent`

Comment: I think the build tools for F# not include in the Hosted agent, see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nosami suggested a workaround, which I'm not very happy about (i.e.: I still think AzureDevops team should fix their default hosted agent to include F# tooling), but does the job: use the `Microsoft.FSharp.Targets` file provided by the nuget package called `FSharp.Compiler.Tools`. [This is the diff](https://github.com/nblockchain/geewallet/commit/da0e265961039bb64db7238984e37b95d7b5c545) in my opensource project if you're curious.

**UPDATE**: In case the above doesn't help or looks too intricated for you, I think one of this two answers could work: [adjusting MSBuild properties of your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25981087/544947) or [using the proper version of MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259125/544947) could work as well and is simpler.